# What is the use of forms.py file and class myform(): in an app when we have CLass Base dViews (CBV)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

As I am new to Django and there is not much information about the use of defining forms.py file with form classes and where are they used. I mean to say that we can do all of the work by CBV, then what is the use of Function based view and explicitly defining Forms classes inside forms.py. Any help would be appreciated.

Edited- Plus, can you customise your form fields in CBV? for example my model has

```
 name=models.CharField()
```

but I want my form to display the label like-

```
    Enter Your First Name
```

How can it be done? I checked Django documentation but couldn't find information on this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer about what is the use of form .....
**The answer is from.py it let me to control about my DB it mean which thing i cloud input from the user**

```
widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={" <label> Enter Your First Name </label> "})
```